# How to get a compiler error for assignments in an if statement?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

Is it possible in Visual Studio to get a compiler error for an assignment in an `if` statement? How?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    if (a = 3)  // Want a warning here
        std::cout << "Avoid this!\n";
}
```

I know I can switch to Yoda conditions (`if (3=a)`), but I really don't want to.

I tried: setting the warning level to `/Wall` but I still don't get a warning that I could then treat as an error.

I am doing this in Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.19).:

[image: Visual Studio 2019]

The build output is

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Yoda2019, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Yoda2019.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\limits.h(70,5): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\limits.h(70,5): warning C4668: '__STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(154,5): warning C4365: 'argument': conversion from 'long' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(164,5): warning C4365: 'argument': conversion from 'long' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic(284,9): warning C4365: 'argument': conversion from 'long' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic(299,9): warning C4365: 'argument': conversion from 'long' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic(315,9): warning C4365: 'argument': conversion from 'long' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic(375,9): warning C4365: 'argument': conversion from 'long' to 'unsigned int', signed/unsigned mismatch
1>Done building project "Yoda2019.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

and Visual Studio 2022 (17.4.0)

[image: Visual Studio 2022]

The build output is

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: YodaCheck, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>YodaCheck.cpp
1>YodaCheck.vcxproj -> B:\Projekte\C++\Dynamic Linking\YodaCheck\x64\Debug\YodaCheck.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:01,379 ==========
```

so I see no warning which I could convert into an error.

Comment: Most compilers will issue a warning, just turn warnings into errors using your specific compile flags

Comment: Isn't `warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression` suitable?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I heard people say so, yes. My question is to how actually do that in Visual Studio.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/MWvn3joEa

Comment: @ThomasWeller in VS 2022 you're configuring `Debug Win32` but building `Debug x64`. In VS 2019 the build fails so it didn't come to the warning stage for that line. Why do you even build Win32 these days?

Comment: @ThomasWeller obviously VS on godbolt.org are the official versions. You can even use https://www.godbolt.ms/ for the Windows-specific site

Comment: @phuclv: I gosh, how I hate these property pages! I always wonder who the heck would configure his debug build so much different from the release build and the x86 build so much different from the x64 build. Never understood that, now I'm running into such a sh*** thing. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Being able to do that is both a blessing and a curse...

Comment: If you have suggestions for how to make the property pages better, I'm sure they'd be happy to entertain suggestions.  Eclipse, Xcode, and the various IDEs from JetBrains folks are no better (imo).  There are just so many properties, many of which interact, that it is overwhelming and bewildering.  Note:  I think highly of VS, Xcode, Eclipse, and Jetbrains — this is just a hard problem.

Comment: @Eljay: well, I think some settings just don't make sense to change individually. I could e.g. set /std:c++14 in Debug build and /std:c++20 in Release build. But why would anyone ever do that? If I use C++20 features, I can't compile my debug build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn any *specific* warning into an error, using the `#pragma warning(error:nnnn)` directive. In your case, the warning is:

> warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression

So, adding the relevant `#pragma` directive to the code will generate a compiler *error*:

```c
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning(error:4706)

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    if (a = 3)  // Want a warning here
        std::cout << "Avoid this!\n";
}
```

This now gives:

> error C4706: assignment within conditional expression

For a solution wide setting, change it here in the property pages:

[image: C4706 in property page]

Comment: Note that this directive will generate an error *whatever* the current warning level is set to in the command-line/project options. Even with `/W1`, I still get the error in VS2022.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited your answer to include a screenshot on how to make a solution wide setting. The main problem for me was my selection of configuration and platform.

Answer (score 7):

Use `/W4 /WX`

> `/WX` Treats all compiler warnings as errors. For a new project, it may be best to use /WX in all compilations; resolving all warnings ensures the fewest possible hard-to-find code defects.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170

Make sure you make that setting in the relevant configurations. In such a simple demo, it's probably easiest to choose "all configurations" and "all platforms".

[image: Visual Studio property pages]

Comment: Or for just C4706 in particular, `#pragma warning( error : 4706 )` is an option.

Comment: I have done this already. See my screenshots in the question. As I said, I don't get a warning for that, so there's nothing to be converted into an error.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't see the switch `/W4` in your question

Comment: @MatG: So W4 is more than Wall?

Comment: no, `/Wall` is higher, but it includes so many redundant warnings so `/W4` is more commonly used

Comment: `/Wall` has so much noise that it's impractical except for those with extreme OCD.  I use `/Wall`.

Comment: Thanks @phluclv. I edited your question to include my main fault, which was an oversight for configuration and platform. (I also needed an edit in order to upvote). I'll accept Adrian Mole's answer, since that specifically targets just the one warning I currently care about.